# JavaMail Api listing header doesnt work

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail, listings

I'm trying to add some listing related header lines in the email header, but it doesn't work..

```
msg.addHeader("List-ID", lmsg.getListId());
msg.addHeader("List-Archive", lmsg.getListId());
msg.setHeader("List-Post", lmsg.getListId());
msg.setHeader("List-Unsubscribe", lmsg.getListId());
msg.setHeader("X-Mailer", mailer);
msg.setSentDate(lmsg.getSendDate());
Transport.send(msg);
```

nothing of the list header lines is in the received mail but the x-mailer line is still in it...

Where ist my fault ?

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing obviously wrong in your code so you'll need to debug it.  Start [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#debug).  Also, before sending the message add msg.writeTo(new FileOutputStream("msg.txt")); and then examine the msg.txt file to be sure it includes the headers.  If it does, and they still don't show up in the recipient's mailbox, some server along the way is removing them.